# Does HVAC lineset need to be grounded?

Tags: electrical, hvac, grounding

My HVAC contractor says the installation of the line set between the air handler and the condenser outside is complete but he has not grounded the lines.

Do HVAC copper pipes need to be grounded?

Comment: A 12 gauge ground wire is not going to be much help in a direct lightning strike. The primary purpose of grounding wires is to provide a safe path for electricity in the case of an appliance malfunction, not to handle 100,000 amps from lightning. I agree with @Ecnerwal below: if you're concerned about lightning you should install equipment appropriate to that purpose.

Comment: I see you removed the portion of your question dealing with lightning. What is it that you're worried about? Any electrical components such as the compressor motor will already be grounded.

Answer (score 1):

Metal lines connected by metal fittings to metal enclosures which actually have power connected to them, and therefore also have grounds connected to them - so, they **already are grounded.**

Comment: my condenser is on the roof of the house

Comment: And it has an electric motor in it to run the compressor, and that electric motor is connected to the electrical system of the house, and is grounded. So the lines are grounded. If you have lightning paranoia issues, install a lightning rod system, don't harass your HVAC installer.

Comment: so if a lightening hits a refrigerant line, it will get grounded through the power supply cable, right ?